# Typings (.d.ts) for JS module

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to generate Typescript typings for [link2aws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/link2aws) so I can use it inside my Angular project. I've generated a .d.ts file, but I still get the error: `TypeError: (new link2aws__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ARN(...)).consoleLink is not a function`.

I'm importing `ARN` from `link2aws` like so:

```
import { ARN } from 'link2aws';
```

And calling it like so:

```
arn = 'arn:aws:...'
let link = new ARN(arn).consoleLink();
```

`link2aws.d.ts`

```
// Type definitions for link2aws
// Project: https://github.com/link2aws/link2aws.github.io#readme
// Definitions by: me <url redacted> 

declare module 'link2aws' {
  class ARN {
    constructor(text: string);
    string(): string;
    console(): string;
    qualifiers(): string[];
    pathLast(): string;
    consoleLink(): string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create typings for an existing module, they have to match the sources.

Citing the usage from the docs

```
new ARN('arn:aws:s3:::abcdefgh1234').consoleLink;
```

So it seems `consoleLink` is not a function but a property of `ARN`.

And when you look at the source code you also see

```
get consoleLink() { ... }
```

which denotes a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) So, indeed, the runtime is right. `consoleLink` (and probably the other properties too, didn't look too much into the details) is not a function and thus can't be called like one.

So a correct typing for that class may be something like

```
class ARN {

  ...

  public consoleLink: string;

}
```